# show that $f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a metric space with metric $d(x,y)$ and $A,B$ are nonempty subspace of $X$. Define the function $f:A \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x,y)=d(x,y)$. Show that $f$ is continuous when $A \times B$ is given the product space topology and $\mathbb{R}$ has standard topology.

Can anyone help me on this?

Remark: There is one extra condition, i.e. $A \cap B= \emptyset$.

Comment: Shouldn't $f: X \times X \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: @TylerHolden: I also think of this too, but in my question sheet, it is written as $f:A \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Perhaps $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ and we give them the product subspace topology?

Comment: The extra condition isn't necessary.

Comment: @TylerHolden: Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $f(a,b)=r\in\Bbb R$, and let $\epsilon>0$; you need to show that there is an open set $U\subseteq A\times B$ such that $f(x,y)\in(r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon)$ whenever $\langle x,y\rangle\in U$. Let $$V=A\cap N\left(a,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad W=B\cap N\left(b,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)\;,$$ where $N(z,s)$ is the open ball in $X$ with centre $z$ and radius $s$. Now let $U=V\times W$, and show that $f(x,y)\in(r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon)$ whenever $\langle x,y\rangle\in U$.

Comment: I thought we are suppose to prove that for any open set in $\mathbb{R}$, its preimage is open in $A \times B$?

Comment: @Idonknow: That follows immediately from what I suggested that you prove. Basically I’m suggesting that you prove that $f$ is continuous at each point of $A\times B$, from which it follows that $f$ is continuous on $A\times B$.

Comment: I see. How you know that we have to let $W$ to be the union of $V$ and $W$? Also how do we know that we have to define $V$ and $W$ to be that form?

Comment: @Idonknow: In the first question did you mean $U=V\times W$ (instead of $W=V\cup W$)? I know that I need an open nbhd of $f(x,y)$ with a certain property, and the basic open sets in the product (i.e., sets of the form $\text{open set}\times\text{open set}$) are the easiest to work with. The simplest open sets in $A$ are those of the form $A\cap N(x,r)$, and the simplest open sets in $B$ are those of the form $B\cap N(x,r)$, so I looked for sets of that form that would do what I wanted. I want a nbhd of $\langle a,b\rangle$, so it certainly makes sense to choose $a$ and $b$ for the centres ...

Comment: ... of the balls. The $\frac{\epsilon}2$ radii was just a matter of seeing what would work; I could have used any smaller radii just as well.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the typo. Thx for your explanation. Another question: How do we know $U$ is open in $A \times B$? Because from what I know, open sets in product topology are the union of basis elements.

Comment: @Idonknow: The $V$ is open in $A$, and $W$ is open in $B$ (both by definition of the subspace topology on a set), so $V\times W$ is open in $A\times B$ by the definition of the product topology.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology In this link, The open sets in the product topology are unions (finite or infinite) of sets of the form $\prod_{i\in I} U_i$, where each $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ and $U_i ≠ X_i$ only finitely many times.

Comment: @Idonknow: Yes. And that last restriction is irrelevant here, since there are only two factors: every open set in $A\times B$ is the union of sets of the form $V\times W$, where $V$ is open in $A$, and $W$ is open in $B$.

Comment: Actually I feel a bit confused about open sets in product topology. We know that all basis elements are open sets in its topology, right? So can I say that any set $V$ opens in $X$ and $W$ opens in $Y$, their product $V \times W$ opens in $X \times Y$? So the open sets in product topology need not be union of some basis elements?

Comment: @Idonknow: Your $V\times W$ **is** a union of basis elements: a union of just one set is perfectly acceptable. Think of it as *a union of one or more sets of the form* $V\times W$.